# Xamarin/Visual studio: Deployment failed. How to troubleshoot

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Im quite new to Xamarin and android development. I have made a new virtual device but when Im trying to run debug (by hitting "play" in Visual Studio) I get the message "Deployment failed", but I cant find any error message or logs.

Any tips on how to find that or troubleshoot for failing deployments?

(I can deploy when using a simple program and the pre-installed kit kat 4.4)

EDIT: 
From output window:

```
Starting deploy 0001 ...
Starting emulator 0001 ...
An error occured. See full exception on logs for more details.
An error occured. See full exception on logs for more details.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: You should probably ask that on the Xamarin forums, the developers often know more about what could cause the deployment to fail - and hell, it does a lot with Xamarin.

Comment: You should have the reason for deployment failed in your output view. If possible check it and post it here.

Comment: @Hari_krish4: Added output window.

Comment: @Ray Koopa: Ok, will do as well

Comment: @Cowborg This is just the last part. If you scroll above in your output view. You can find the error. Or else open Android studio run the app in the device and see logcat.

Comment: You'll probably want to run [adb logcat -c] and then [adb logcat -vtime -d > "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\android_logcat.txt"] (or simply open device log from View > Other Windows > Android Device Logging) and deploy again.  Turning on diagnostic build output might also help - https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/#Diagnostic_MSBuild_Output

Comment: Thanks for all help. I actually gave up and am running with a real device for now. I will keep these tips though,, for another go at it later. @Alan: If you post the same text in an answer I can set it as the correct answer.